# Print text file every three line start at 2nd line

Tags: sed, awk

I have done it with simple loop to count and print through.. How can I do it in bash scripting with program such as sed,awk ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
awk 'NR % 3 == 2'
```

> Test

```
sh-3.2$ more test
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

> Result

```
sh-3.2$ awk 'NR % 3 == 2' < test
2
5
8
11
14
```

Comment: `awk 'NR % 3 == 2'` is a much simpler expression.

Comment: done @glennjackman :=)

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this with GNU sed:

```
seq 20 | sed -n '2~3p'
```

Output:

```
2
5
8
11
14
17
20
```